# Yii cgridview drop down filter not working on second page

Tags: gridview, yii, yii-filters

I've drop down filter in CGridView.
1. On first page filter with filter value it's worked.
2. go to second page of filter secord.
3. apply filter by selecting another value from drop down the drop down value is post but grid not filter with current selected value. it's showing result on old filter value.

1. fist time filter below data is in GET['MyForm']

```php
Array
(

    [MyForm] => Array
    (
        [NameSearch] => 
        [CitySearch] => 
        [Status] => 1
    )

    [MyForm_page] => 1
    [ajax] => myForm-grid

)
```

2. on second page of filter record below data is in GET['MyForm']

```php
Array
(

    [MyForm] => Array
    (
        [NameSearch] => 
        [CitySearch] => 
        [Status] => 1
    )

    [MyForm_page] => 2
    [ajax] => myForm-grid

)
```

both the time GET data is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **URL Management** the ajax path getting as for default Yii framework so I used in **CGridView** and it solved by problem

```
'ajaxUrl' => $this->createUrl('site/myForm'),
```

Use of above code the filter is formatted as your rules set in URL Management.